# Inputting large numbers and check if it is prime (Python)

Tags: python, rsa

I am making a program using python wherein it checks large numbers if it is a prime number or not. (this is for RSA Encryption)

Here is my code:

```
p = int(input("Enter first prime number: "))

while(1):
    if isPrime(p) is False:
        print("%d is not a prime number!" % p)
        p = int(input("Please enter first prime number again: "))
    else:
        print("%d is a prime number." % p)
        break

q = int(input("Enter second prime number: "))

while(1):
    if isPrime(q) is False:
        print("%d is not a prime number!" % q)
        q = int(input("Please enter second prime number again: "))
    else:
        print("%d is a prime number." % q)
        break
```

p is the first large number and q is the second large number.

here is the function that checks if it is a prime number:

```
def isPrime(num):

    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if(num % i) == 0:
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

I tried running it using small numbers like 17 and 11 and it works but when I tried to input a 16-digit number, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is the sample run:
[image: p = 17 and q = 11]

[image: here i entered a large number]

On the second image, when I entered a large number, it does not continue. I tried waiting for half an hour and see if it works but it still, it's just like that. Why is it so?

Comment: If that number is prime, how many times do you think it will have to run through the `for` loop in `isPrime`?  Computers are fast, but it does take a finite amount of time to run each calculation.  There are more efficient ways to test for primality, including some methods that are fast but non-deterministic (there is some very tiny probability that the test returns the wrong answer).  You might need to look into those.

Comment: Just for completeness, you only have to check up to sqrt(n) to determine if n is prime.  That would take your example down to 37 million loops, which is do-able.

Comment: Why did you delete the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66489876/1820553)? This is disrespect to the answerer. You should ask to the answerer before doing that. We spend time on your problem!.

Comment: hello, @kelalaka I'm sorry I didn't know. I already know the answer to my question. Tho thank you for answering the question. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's taking so long because you're looping over A LOT of numbers, every one up until your 16 digit one, which is a lot of loop iterations. Even if you're only doing constant work per iteration, getting through that many numbers will still take awhile. Loops in python are notoriously slow. Luckily, you can use `sympy` like so:

```
from sympy.ntheory import factorint
def isPrime(n):
    return len(factorint(n)) == 1
```

and then things should be going much faster. For reference:

```
factorint(133453565475464563453)
```

took about half a second

Comment: hello, thank you for telling me about this library. It worked flawlessly on my program. T___T I used the .isprime() method using sympy :)) thank youu

Comment: Happy to be of help, `isprime` is a bit cleaner but I didn't even know about it until today!

Comment: The sympy [`isprime()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.primetest.isprime) is the correct one to use, `factorint` will be too slow for larger integers that are composite. However, for numbers larger than 64 bits the test is probabilistic and thus with very small probability may report a number as prime that is really a composite.